# I am not able to post data collection from knockout to my webapi service

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am not able to post data collection from knockout to my webapi service.

My knockout code:

```
 $.ajax("/api/tasks/PostTask", {
                    data: ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks }),
                    type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (result) { alert(result) }
                });
            };
```

if i put the output of ko.toJSON({ tasks: self.tasks }) to a div tag the result is:

{"tasks":[{"title":"task# 0","isDone":false},{"title":"task# 1","isDone":false},{"title":"task# 2","isDone":false},{"title":"task# 3","isDone":false},{"title":"task# 4","isDone":false},{"title":"task# 5","isDone":false}]}

so, iam sending data.

My webapi method:

```
 public void PostTaskCollection(List<Task> tasks)
    {

        foreach (Task item in tasks)
        {
            string _title = item.title;
        }

    }
```

when i put a breakpoint in, i see that the tasks variable is null.  What am i doing wrong? Why doesn't the collection get passed to my webapi method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your `self.tasks` in a new object otherwise Web.Api won't bind correctly because of the `"tasks"` prefix. So just write `ko.toJSON(self.tasks)`.

So this call should work:

```
$.ajax("/api/tasks/PostTask", {
        data: ko.toJSON(self.tasks),
        type: "post",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) { alert(result); }
    });
```